Teste T pareado em inguagem R: cannot use 'paired' in formula method
Tudo funciona até eu colocar o argumento paired = T, então ele dá a seguinte mensagem:
Error in t.test.formula(polinizadores ~ tratamento, paired = T, alternative = "l",  :
cannot use 'paired' in formula method
Podem me ajudar?

A mensagem de erro é bem clara. Não é possível utilizar a sintaxe (ou método) de fórmula para fazer um Teste T Pareado no R. A solução é utilizar a sintaxe tradicional, dada por
t.test(grupo_1, grupo_2, data = dados, paired = TRUE)

Como não foi fornecido um CMR para o problema, resolverei ele utilizando o conjunto de dados sleep, disponível com qualquer instalação do R.
O primeiro passo a ser tomado é colocar os dados no formado wide (largo), como especificado neste link:
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'janitor'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     chisq.test, fisher.test

sleep_wide <- 
  sleep |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = extra) |> 
  clean_names()


sleep_wide |> 
  select(-id) |> 
  summarise_all(mean)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>      x1    x2
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  0.75  2.33

Note as médias de 0.75 e 2.33 para ambos os grupos. Desta forma, a diferença x1 - x2 é igual a -1.58, como mostrado no output abaixo.
t.test(sleep_wide$x1, sleep_wide$x2, paired = TRUE)
#> 
#>  Paired t-test
#> 
#> data:  sleep_wide$x1 and sleep_wide$x2
#> t = -4.0621, df = 9, p-value = 0.002833
#> alternative hypothesis: true mean difference is not equal to 0
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  -2.4598858 -0.7001142
#> sample estimates:
#> mean difference 
#>           -1.58

Além disso, como p-valor = 0.002833 < 0.05, a hipótese nula é rejeitada e há diferença significativa entre os grupos.
Mas se fizer questão de usar os dados no formato longo, é possível ajustar um modelo linear misto a estes dados, considerando group como efeito fixo e id como efeito aleatório:
library(lme4)
library(emmeans)

modelo <- lmer(extra ~ group + (1|ID), data = sleep)

contrast(emmeans(modelo, ~ group), "pairwise")
#>  contrast        estimate    SE df t.ratio p.value
#>  group1 - group2    -1.58 0.389  9  -4.062  0.0028
#> 
#> Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger

Note como no output acima temos os mesmos resultados do Teste T Pareado em termos de estimativa, erro padão, graus de liberdade, estatística do teste e p-valor, mostrando que ambos os métodos são equivalentes.
Created on 2024-05-24 with reprex v2.1.0
